# Problem in posting after inserting text in landscape mode

Tags: bug

I notice the app **Stack Exchange** for mobile has a bug. Namely, if I use *landscape* mode for input, and then I press the *post* button, the app doesn't send the message, and it doesn't work anymore, also after changing in *portrait* mode (I tested this with comments).

Comment: If this is the bug I'm thinking of, it's not that you wrote it in landscape, it's that you switched orientation after clicking the "add comment" button. The app handles orientation switches extremely poorly. As a rule of thumb, expect things to break if you switch orientation while in the middle of something. Also note that development of the app is suspended/terminated until further notice, so this likely won't be fixed. I use the app almost exclusively, and this is one of 2-3 major bugs that make my life difficult.